# Why p-adic log on $1 +p \Bbb{Z}_p$ is continuous?

Tags: logarithms, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Why log on $1 +p \Bbb{Z}_p$ ($log:1 +p \Bbb{Z}_p→\Bbb{C}_p)$is continuous ?
We can define p-adic logarithm on $x∈1 +p \Bbb{Z}_p$ by $log(1＋x)＝x-x^2/2＋x^3/3-x^4/4・・・$.

My book reads, **log is clearly continuous**.

Why can I say log is continuous ? I know convergence radius is $1$. All topology is p adic topology.

Comment: Hint: the uniform limit theorem

Comment: p adic version of this holds ? Then, I got it. But how can I prove p adic version of this ?https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Converges_to_Continuous_Function

Comment: Because it is clearly continuous :-) If $v_p(a)  >0$ then $v_p(a^n/n) > n/2$ so $\log(1+a)\bmod p^k$ depends only on $a\bmod p^{2k}$

Comment: If *power series* were not continuous inside their radius of convergence, life would not be worth living.

Comment: The same argument for continuity of power series in their radius of convergence from real analysis works in any field with an absolute value.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg   Poetic. Impressed.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg infinite products of the form $\prod_{n \geq 1} (1 + a_nx^n)$ can need not be continuous on their *boundary*, and likewise for Euler products.

Comment: See Theorem 3.12 and Corollary 3.14 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf.  I am kind of surprised you'd be reading a book that says the logarithm power series is continuous without having *earlier* shown $p$-adic power series are continuous on their disc of convergence. What book are you reading?

Comment: @KCd: I was aware of that and tried to phrase "*inside* their radius [should have said: disk] of convergence" clear enough there. What happens on the boundary is one of those edgy things that can make life more interesting. But one needs some solid ground to retreat back to sometimes.

Comment: Neukirch extends this logarithm to $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$ by $\log(\alpha)=v_p(\alpha)K + \log(\langle \alpha \rangle)$ where $K$ is carefully chosen, $\alpha=p^{v_p(\alpha)}\omega(\alpha)\langle \alpha \rangle \in \mathbb{Q}_p^\times$, $\omega(\alpha) \in \mu_{p-1}$ and $\langle \alpha \rangle \in 1 + p\mathbb{Z}_p$ (see Algebraic Number Theory, Neukirch (5.4) p. 136). He says that this extension is clearly continuous. But I don’t see why… Could you help me ?